# Typescript Generics and rxjs map

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

How can we write a generic RXJS `map` function, and use it like an error handler applied to an Angular Http observable ?

I have tried :

```
registerUser(user: CreateUserAPI) {
  interface res  {
    session_key?: string;
    result?: string;
    error?: string;
  }

  return this.http
    .post<res>(`${API_URL}/api/customer/register`, user)
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError), map(this.captureError));
}

captureError<T>(res: T): T {
  if (res.error) { // <== TS ERROR : Property 'error' does not exist on type 'T'
    Raven.captureMessage(res.error);
  }
  return res;
}

test(){
    let user : any
    this.registerUser(user).subscribe(res => {
      res.error // no error
    })
  }
```

But TS is returning the error : `Property 'error' does not exist on type 'T'`

My goal is to keep the typing of my observable when I subscribe to it later (`test()` method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set that your generic type extends interface with `error` property:

```
interface ErrorObj {
  error: string;
}

captureError<T extends ErrorObj>(res: T): T {
  if (res.error) {
    Raven.captureMessage(res.error);
  }
  return res;
}
```